# Disable antd DatePicker future pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, antd

I`m building a website with React and antd library, I have a datepicker like this one:

```
<RangePicker
          format={'DD/MM/YYYY'}
          onChange={onDatePick}
          onOpenChange={onOpenChange}
          onCalendarChange={val => setDates(val)}
          disabledDate={disabledDate}
          value={hackValue || value}
        />
```

I would like to disable ability for user to scroll calendar past present month and before January 2016. Right now I have those dates disabled so user cannot choose them but can steel see dated past or before those dates.
I mean using this arrows:
[image: Screenshot with mentioned arrows]

Comment: Developer says use HOC to solve these types of problems:

Comment: @RandyCasburn I'm not quite sure i understand how to do this. Can you please clarify a little bit?

Comment: [this article will explain](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) - A Higher Order Component is basically a wrapper around another component. Looks like antd authors expect you to write a HOC to wrap their component. Then you'll need to add the methods to disable all those buttons, all the cascaded popups for years, months and days in order to style the buttons the way you want. Good luck to you.